# I get connection error when I add my database name in connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user '-----'@'localhost' to database '----' in ---.php on line 4
Unable to connect to MySQL

```
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
```

This is how I connect. If I remove DB_NAME from there, I don't get an error and connect database but whenever I add DB_NAME, I get this error. DB_NAME is definitely correct but I don't see why? By the way for DB_HOST, I use localhost.

---

---Solved---

I finally solved the problem. So, for those of you who have the same problem, I am gonna explain everything. Actually, I decided to use table name before my query and than mysqli gave me another error saying something like "INSERT command denied to user ..." So, I opened up phpMyAdmin and changed my DB_USER to the name that is written in Database Server section in phpMyAdmin. You will see something like this;

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.42-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: -HERE-
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

So you need to use use the username, which is written in User part. After I changed my DB_USER I was able to add DB_NAME. Basically all the problems I was having (not being able to use DB_NAME and not being able to use sql commands) caused my permission.

The key part is; I was using DB_NAME, which I used to create database in my server and it also let me connect to the database but As I can see it is not the root. So, if you are having "denied" error, make sure that you check the values you typed in mysqli_connect!

Comment: FYI: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-connecting.html

Comment: Permissions issue, maybe?

Comment: what do you mean permission? I already wrote my password and username.

Comment: Are you working on a server? or in Localhost?

Comment: in the ipage server.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
@ mysqli_connect(hostname, username, password, database)
```

or

```
@mysqli_connect(hostname,username, password) 
@ mysqli_select_db(true, database);
```

or

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed : mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"db");
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using localhost then try this

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "",  "YOUR_DB_NAME");
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die ("Could not Connect");
    }
?>
```

and if you are doing this online then replace `localhost` with `host_name` `root` with `username` `""` with `password` and at last your `DB_Name`. I hope this would solve your problem :)